# Links from included template Twig do not work on the template they appear

Tags: symfony, twig

So I building a website using Symfony 5. Since I have several pages, I created a "header.html.twig" template which is the header of the website containing the logo, the research bar and other buttons plus the nav bar and also created a "footer.html.twig" template. The purpose was to include those templates inside my pages to have less code and let it clear.
I used the twig include function to do it and it doesn't work properly.
Links from header or footer do not work on other pages except from the home page.

header.html.twig doesn't extend base.html.twig

I've included like this for exemple in my product detail page

```
 {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ product.productName }}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="container-lg">
    
    {% block header %}
    
        {{ include('header.html.twig') }}

    {% endblock %}
    
    <div class="main-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

        <div class = "container float-left bg-light rounded mt-4 p-4 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center justify-content-between"> 

            <div class="left-part-container d-flex flex-column">
    
                <div class="slider-container">
            
                    <div class="slider">
                        <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2"/>
                        <label for="id2">
                        <img src="/public/images/products/{{ product.image }}" alt="{{ product.productName }}" width="50" height = "75px"/>
                        </label>
                        <img src="/public/images/products/{{ product.image }}" alt="{{ product.productName }}" class = "ss"/>
                        
                        {% for attachment in product.attachments %}
                        <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1" checked="checked"/>
                        <label for="id1">
                        <img src="/public/images/products/{{ attachment.image }}" alt="{{ product.productName }}" width="50" height = "75px"/>
                        </label>
                        <img src="/public/images/products/{{ attachment.image }}" alt="{{ product.productName }}"  class = "ss"/>
                        {% endfor %}
                      
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
        {% block footer %}
        
        {{ include('footer.html.twig') }}

        {% endblock %}

               
{% endblock %}
```

Does anybody can help?

Comment: you should include them outside the block {% body %]. the block body in the layout or base.html.twig should be blank

Comment: Could you add an example of "other pages" extending this layout?

Comment: @hous I've tried but the included template doesn't even show!

Comment: try to include them directly without {% block header %} and {% block footer %}. because when you put theme inside block, you should call all those  blocks in the others views

Comment: @hous It doesn't work too... All the links from my header are pointing to the current page. I mean, If I'm on a product page when I'm pointing on the nav bar, are the links display the current product page link.

Comment: @qdequippe I've added an example

Comment: what do you mean by links ? href links or assets  like images ? show us some code of the header

Comment: I mean when included href change to the current page... In my header I have The logo pointing to homepage and a nav bar